# Are polytheistic society more peaceful than monotheistic ones?

Tags: social-psychology, cross-cultural-psychology, religion, aggression

News last day have brought some thoughts in my mind, if a religion is a good choice for peace and when yes which one. My conclusion was at this step, that maybe polytheistic religions are more peaceful and therefore better for a society. But, is this true? Is there a relation between the peacefulness of a society and if its believe is mono- or polytheistic?

Answers and sources are highly appreciated, looking forward for your answers,
greetings

Comment: Interesting question.  However, the number of monotheistic religions might be too small to achieve statistical significance trying to answer it, and considering that virtually all of them have the same (zoroastrianism) origin, there may be too many other confounding factors to isolate just the desired variable.  So I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Polytheistic brings up the association with "tribal", and there has been studies that show that death rate in tribal wars is close to 60%: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Before_Civilization

Comment: Minimizing the number of gods seems to be a way to become more peaceful, when you think of buddhism for example...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more on the topic of *sociology* than psychology.

Comment: I sea the point that it is opinion based (without many proves). But since this boards name is "cognitive science" and psychology and sociology isn't clearly seperatable I don't see your point. Furthermore you don't have to analyze this by the whole culture, you can also only watch at the aggression of one single human. I think a logic proof would be more in direction about holding your own bad feelings "cool" and which religion supports this lifestyle more. But if you have data about war/religion data, you are highly welcome.